# Memory leak of java.lang.ref.WeakReference objects inside JDK classes

Tags: java, jvm, logging, memory-leaks, weak-references

The following simple code reproduces the growth of `java.lang.ref.WeakReference` objects in the heap:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

while (true) {
java.util.logging.Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
Thread.sleep(1);
}
}
```

Here is the output of jmap command within a few seconds interval:

```
user@t1007:~> jmap -d64 -histo:live 29201|grep WeakReference
8: 22493 1079664 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
31: 1 32144 [Ljava.lang.ref.WeakReference;
106: 17 952

com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.WeakIdentityHashMap$IdentityWeakReference
user@t1007:~> jmap -d64 -histo:live 29201|grep WeakReference
8: 23191 1113168 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
31: 1 32144 [Ljava.lang.ref.WeakReference;
103: 17 952

com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.WeakIdentityHashMap$IdentityWeakReference
user@t1007:~> jmap -d64 -histo:live 29201|grep WeakReference
8: 23804 1142592 java.lang.ref.WeakReference
31: 1 32144 [Ljava.lang.ref.WeakReference;
103: 17 952 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.WeakIdentityHashMap$IdentityWeakReference
```

Note that jmap command forces FullGC.

```
JVM settings:
export JVM_OPT="\
-d64 \
-Xms200m -Xmx200m \
-XX:MaxNewSize=64m \
-XX:NewSize=64m \
-XX:+UseParNewGC \
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10 \
-XX:SurvivorRatio=2 \
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60 \
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly \
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled \
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC \
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps \
-XX:+PrintGCDetails \
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution \
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime \
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime \
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime \
-XX:+PrintClassHistogram \
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled \
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=1 \
-verbose:gc \
-Xloggc:$GCLOGFILE"
```

---

```
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)

Solaris 10/Sun Fire(TM) T1000
```

Answer (score 5):

Fixed in 1.6.0_29: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u29-relnotes-507960.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen

1.6.0_29 is not mentioned on the bug page itself ( https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6942989 ), so I thought it'd be useful to post the link there so the fact it's been fixed is discoverable.

Answer (score 4):

I have reproduced this on 1.6.0_19.

If you run the sample application with these java arguments:

-Xms8m -Xmx8m -XX:MaxPermSize=8m

After 10 - 15 minutes it will produce an OutOfMemoryError.

I have filed a bug report with Sun. They will let me know in due time if it has been accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, it will be fixed in JDK 7. At https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6942989 , it says:
Release Fixed   7(b102)

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed under JDK 1.6.0_19 and 1.6.0_20, absent under 1.6.0_17:

java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)

References leaking pile up in java.util.logging.Logger#kids array, but most probably changes in LogManager caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Sun has accepted this bug in their tracker, but for some reason its not showing up on their website, so I cannot post a link here (yet). Talking to Sun right now to ask them what happened.